# C# Open source album application

Tags: looking-for-a-script, open-source, photo-gallery, c#

For privacy reasons, I'm searching for an open source album application I can host on my server, Is there such a project? In C#?

I'd like to upload pictures, tag them, have privileges settings etc.

10x

Answer (score 4):

You maybe found what you need with [Microsoft WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/).

[Composite C1](http://www.composite.net/C1/CMS.aspx) (directly available in WebMatrix) is an Open Source heavily customizable CMS in C#, that can allow you to use it as an album application.

You can also take a look to [Photo Gallery Wall C#](http://photogallerywallcs.codeplex.com/), a Silverlight Photo Gallery based on [this tutorial](http://designwithsilverlight.com/?p=162) ([here a demonstration](http://designwithsilverlight.com/tutorials/photoGalleryWall/Default.html)).

Answer (score 1):

Do you try Galleris section in WebMatrix, there are 4 application , I tries Gallery Server Pro, but I'm not sure it was in C#

Answer (score 1):

GalleryServerpro is a pretty good product; I have used it on some sites with very little difficulty and the developer is very good about answering questions if you need help.
[http://www.galleryserverpro.com](http://www.galleryserverpro.com/)